# How to get row selection event and item click event in custom adapter listview all together in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, android-event

I have custom list of two text views having different text string. These are items in the list. In current scenerio I can only register the setOnItemClickListener for the list. This is triggered when the item in the list is clicked. If I click on the other portion of the row, no event is generated..

How can I have the item click as well as the row click event all together, so that wherever I click on the row of the list an event is triggered.

Comment: You need to click cell of listView or textview independently ?

Comment: add click listener for main layout as well as text/button that you want to click  and check click on onClick(View v) method what is clicked using layout id

Comment: @Piyush - Wherever I click whether it be the textview or the cell of listview, I need to call a single function. Currently I can register only the setOnItemClickListener event, which means only if i click on any of the textview do I get the event.

Comment: @J Ramesh - I did that but can't register the onClick  event for list as well as items in list...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by implementing callback Interface.

Implement onClickListener for a particular view and use callback listener to get the callback to you fragment or activity.

Comment: I have already implemented the callback register which works fine when an Item is clicked. I need to register callback on item click of a list as well as row click of a list.

Comment: ListView itemsListView  = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view_items);
RoomsListAdapter adapter = new RoomsListAdapter(this, generateItemsList());
itemsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        
itemsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                Log.d(TAG,item);
                Log.d(TAG,"Item Clicked");
            } });